# Copy file from Debian to Mac OS X or Windows

Tags: macos, unix

I'm new to Linux. How can I copy a file or directory from the Debian OS to Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can share filesystems across these platforms but this requires some basic network/sharing configuration on all involved systems.

### Sharing via Filesystems

On OS X you can enable File Sharing in System Preferences -> Sharing

[image]

By default only AFP sharing is enabled which may not be available in a standard Linux setup (and definitively is not available on Windows). To also enable Samba/Windows sharing, click on "Options..." and enable Samba sharing there.

### Sharing via Syncing solution

An alternative and rather easy approach would be to install either [Dropbox](https://db.tt/sntDE9m) or [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) on all systems and use this to copy data over.

### Copying with `scp`

In case you only want to copy some files you might also be able to use `scp` to copy files from/to a remote system over a network. Basic syntax is

```
scp local-file remote-user@remote-host:
```

and you will be prompted to enter the password of `remote-user`.